# How to get all orders items by product_id?

Tags: magento2, product, orders, magento2.3.1

I want to get all order items by product_id not by order_id. So Please read carefully and give me a solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: where you want all order, i mean for what purpose?

Comment: Ok, let me explain you. If I did many orders such in one order there are 2 items means products then in other order other products. So I need to get all ordered product list by separate order. because I need to check which options were selected by buyer in separate orders.

Comment: i have posted the answer as per your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code with changes according to your needs, and do not use object manager in original implementation.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderItemCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\Collection');
$orderItemCollection->addFieldToFilter('order_id', ORDER_ID);
$orderItemCollection->addFieldToFilter('product_id', PRODUCT_ID);

foreach ($orderItemCollection as $item) 
{
    $options = $item->getProductOptions();
}
```